# How much data can I store in NSUserDefaults in iWatch app series 2 without iPhone?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watch, watchos-2

We want to create an app that will store event information, and I want to use UserDefaults for storing events data.So please suggest me how much data we can store in iWatch app series 2 without iPhone or device?

Answer (score 0):

As long as there's space on the iPhone/iPad, you can store NSUserDefault values. All the values are stored in a .plist file.

Comment: I know it but I want to store in iWatch without iPhone.

Comment: The same is true for iWatch, it depends on the available memory. I think the total is 8GB for iWatches